# Cant seem to shrink fatten this the way I want

Tags: scale

[image]

So this root system as you can see have a very thick volume. As -i try scaling it just goes into a smaller rubble, or if I shrink fatten it doesnt respond the way I wish it to do either? Or am I just using the tools incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to shrink and fatten vertices/nodes when using skin modifier